# How to use custom made django template tags inside django-tables2?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-tables2

I have implemented django-tables2 in my project to load my data faster. I have `mytags.py` consists of many of custom made template tags. Can some help me how can I implement my tags into my html? The following is an example of one of my tag and how i implemented in my html before the implementation of django-tables2. Thanks in advance.

html:

```
<td>{{ table.start_time|get_total:table.Date_Time_End|default:"---" }}</td>
```

tag:

```
@register.filter
def get_total(date_start=None, date_end=None):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    if date_start is not None and date_end is not None:
        ds = str(date_start)
        new_ds = ds[:19]
        de = str(date_end)
        new_de = de[:19]
        date_start = datetime.strptime(new_ds, fmt)
        date_end = datetime.strptime(new_de, fmt)
        return date_end - date_start
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want additional field in your table - try this

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    # here your fields

    @property
    def total_date(self):
        fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        if self.date_start is not None and self.date_end is not None:
            ds = str(self.date_start)
            new_ds = ds[:19]
            de = str(self.date_end)
            new_de = de[:19]
            date_start = datetime.strptime(new_ds, fmt)
            date_end = datetime.strptime(new_de, fmt)

            return date_end - date_start
        else:
            return None
```

Then add it to your table class fields

```
class YourTableClass(tables.Table):
    total_date = tables.Column(verbose_name='Total date')

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
```